# SFCrypto "keychain data missing or corrupted"

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Intermittently getting the following error when logging in to iOS iPad app using Salesforce Mobile SDK.

> 2014-10-01 16:35:32:177 iPath[3381:60b] ERROR|SFCrypto|App id keychain
>   data missing or corrupted. Attempting to reset.
>
> 2014-10-01 16:35:32:192 iPath[3381:60b]
>   ERROR|SFKeychainItemWrapper|Error adding keychain item: (-34018)
>
> 2014-10-01 16:35:32:192 iPath[3381:60b] WARN|SFCrypto|Could not save
>   the base app identifier to the keychain (result: Unknown status code
>   (-34018)). Retrying.
>
> 2014-10-01 16:35:32.204 iPath[3381:60b]
>   SFOAuthCredentials:tokenForKey: (-34018) error retrieving
>   "com.salesforce.oauth.access" item matching "{ acct =
>   "iPath-Default-login.salesforce.com"; class = genp; "m_Limit" =
>   "m_LimitOne"; "r_Attributes" = 1; svce =
>   "com.salesforce.oauth.access"; }"

Any ideas on cause or fix? Thanks

Comment: Which xcode and sdk version you are using?

Comment: Xcode 5.1.1, I think I'm using SDK 2.1, how do I verify?